# In PhpStorm branch names are preceded by a plus sign "+"

Tags: git, phpstorm

This is mysterious. I'm using licensed PhpStorm 2021.2 build 2021-07-28 with my own remote GIT server, on Windows 10, and it works great.

> git version 2.32.0.windows.2

I am using worktree branches (BTW it's a great feature).
A couple of weeks ago PhpStorm asked me to upgrade my git so it did. Since the upgrade when I try to merge from another local tracked branch a weird "+" sign appears in front of the worktree branches, and now I cannot continue the merge. Hitting Merge button does nothing.
Before the update I didn't have this problem. I also don't have any problem merging branches outside the worktree, or origin branches.

Does anyone knows what's going on and how to fix that?

[image: screenshot]

When I run `git branch` from the command line I see a column in front of every branch, and some of them (worktree ones) has that evil "+" sign.

```
+ v4.8
+ v50
  v50_kfir
  remotes/origin/brazil_prd
  remotes/origin/brazil_v3.31
```

Comment: I have the same versions and do not have this problem. Can you see the same result in a terminal?

Comment: How does it "prevent" you from continuing the merge? What happens if you pick that branch anyway?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but wanted to point out that AFAIK all IDEA-based IDEs share the git code, so you might find the answer if you search for IDEA-related answers.

Comment: Could you please run `git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false branch --no-color -a --no-merged ` and see if you have the same output? IDE relies on command-line git and displays what Git gives to IDE.

Comment: @JoachimSauer it does nothing. the dialog closes and nothing happens.

Comment: @oriadam [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) say "Any branches checked out in linked worktrees will be highlighted in cyan and marked with a plus sign.". It seems weird that this would break IDEA, though.

Comment: @RuslanKuleshov I added the info to the question. `git branch` gives the same output btw

Comment: @JoachimSauer exactly... and I couldn't find anything on PhpStorm documentation or help regarding this problem. it happens both on my office pc and my home pc (both using the same versions of OS, IDE, git)